# How to use 32 bit winehq temporary

Tags: wine, 64-bit

I use UbuntuStudio 18.04.1 LTS and WineHQ 3.0.4.

The WineHQ installation is as 64 bit version and it works so fine.

But... I want to install an specific version of Adobe AIR which, because some reason, its installer doesn't run into 64 bit WineHQ.

However, believe it or not, once we can install that Adobe AIR version, it runs so fine into WineHQ 64 bit mode!

In other words, it is some bug with the Adobe AIR installer only!

Can I run that installer into 32 bit WineHQ only, but in a temporary mode (without to change all the WineHQ installation itself)?

How?